# SQL Implementation of IF/ELSE breaking result output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query.

```
DECLARE @testvar varchar
DECLARE @rescount int

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
select distinct value from [table] where tablevalId = n

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @testvar
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

select @rescount =  Count(value2) from [table] where value = @testvar and tablevalId = n
if @rescount > 1
    BEGIN 
    select top (@rescount - 1) value2 from [table] where value = @testvar and tablevalId = n order by tablevalue3 desc --This is the value I want
    END
else
    BEGIN
    select @rescount = 1  --This is a 'DO NOTHING'
    END
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @testvar
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

I am trying to get a few groups of records minus the first record in each group. The issue came in where the @rescount was not greater than 1. That is when the IF/ELSE was implemented.

Before the IF/ELSE, it would print the result but break when the @rescount was not greater than 1. Now, it prints nothing and tells me "The Query Was Completed Successfully".

Would anyone be able to advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see you printing the value at all - you're *setting* the value equal to 1 with `SELECT @rescount = 1`.

Comment: I imagined the Select statement in the IF would give me the results. The `select @rescount = 1` is a 'Do Nothing' for the ELSE

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using cursors for this?  Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by tablevalId, value
                                     order by tablevalue3 desc) as seqnum
      from [table] t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

You should avoid cursors if you do not need them.

Comment: I will give it a try now :)

Comment: this function does not remove the first row from the values. which is the issue that forced me into this cursor situation...

Comment: I do like the `row_number()` function though. It should come in handy in future :)

Comment: @jaredlee.exe . . . I think the `= 1` should be a `> 1`.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the problem